# Angular nested directive, order of compilation with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have nested Angular directives like this:

```
<div d1>  
    <div d2></div>  
</div>
```

It compiles as expected like :

1. pre d1
2. pre d2
3. post d2
4. post d1

Unfortunately, if I add a templateUrl reference to d2, the order of compilation changes to:

1. pre d1
2. post d1
3. pre d2
4. post d2

Why is it like this ?
Is there a way to use the first order when using templates ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

The template needs to compile its contents first to add it later to the node. That is why you see this order. Why you need this order?

Comment: I need to run a jQuery plugin on the d1-element after d2 (or multiple nested elements/directives) are rendered.
Is there any way to get a callback after all d2's are rendered ?

Comment: You can use require to get the controller of the d1 directive. Or also you can compile the content inside d1 and add it dynamically that way you know it d2 was rendered and you can execute your jquery plugin.